# Error invalid form control with name='seleccionarCalificacion' is not focusable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ayuda por favor tengo este error en mi formulario pero veo que es por el required pero necesito que si o si los select de mi formulario sean seleccionados por favor como puedo solucionarlo???
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto que es por el required del input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoOrdenTrabajo" id="codigoOrdenTrabajo" minlength="5" maxlength="5" required>
```

pero no he hallado mejor respuesta al respecto

Comment: No es tu primera pregunta. Sabes que si no nos mostras algo, no podemos ayudarte... lee por favor [ask]

Comment: lo siento tienes razon ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: El error es en el elemento con nombre `seleccionarCalificacion`, nada que ver con `codigoOrdenTrabajo` y, jugando al adivino, probablemente lo tengas deshabilitado hasta que se cumplan otras condiciones, pero intentas establecer el foco.